# Surface integral over paraboloid and disk

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

> Let $S$ be the surface composed of the paraboloid $y=x^2+z^2$, with $y \in [0,1]$ and the disk $x^2+z^2 \leq 1$ and $y=1$, oriented with outward normal vectors. Find $\iint_S \mathbf{F} d\mathbf{S}$, where $\mathbf{F}=(0,y,-z)$. (The answer should be 0)

My attempt: Parameterized the paraboloid using parameters $r$ and $\theta$: $x=r\cos\theta$, $z=r\sin\theta$, $y=r^2$. Not sure if this is right and I'm not sure what to do with the disk. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluation is much easier by using the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement),
$$\iint_S \mathbf{F} d\mathbf{S}=\iiint_V\text{div}(\mathbf{F})dV$$
where $V=\{(x,y,z): x^2+z^2\leq y\leq 1\}$.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @user483926 Any progress with the integral?